# Function not executing through all the rows

Tags: python

Need help understanding why this is only returning the results for the first row and not the remaining rows inside a csv file. Thank you

```
with open('customerData.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for rows in reader:
        data.append(rows)
print(data[0])
print(data[1]["Name"])
print(data[2]["Zip"])
print(data[3]["Gender"])
print(data[3]["Favorite Radio Station"])
```

Comment: You're only printing one row, not all the rows.

Comment: `data[0]` is the first row, `data[1]` is the second row, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing items in a list, you can use the `[]` notation to indicate which item in the list you want. The first item in the list is `some_list[0]`, the second is `some_list[1]`, and so on. You can also go from the end of the list, where `some_list[-1]` is the last item, and `some_list[-2]` is the second to last, and so on.

However you want to print every row, you would need to iterate through the list like so:

```
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

From here you can reference the keys of the item in the list directly, in a similar manner to how you did originally in your code:

```
for item in data:
    print(item["Name"])
    print(item["Zip"])
    print(item["Gender"])
```

Hope this helps!